# Rate Distortion Function for a Particular Gaussian Field

Tags: stochastic-processes, it.information-theory

I need to compute the rate distortion function for a random field $g(t,x)$ that arises in Geophysical modelling and that is defined below.

Let $\rho$ be zero-mean Gaussian random process with a squared exponential autocovariance function:

$$K_{\rho}(z_1, z_2) = e^{-\frac{(z_2-z_1)^2}{a^2}}$$

for some correlation length $a$.

Let $g(t,x)$ be a random field defined for $x\ge0$, $t\ge0$ and given in terms of the Gaussian random process $\rho$ and its first derivative.

$$g(t, x) = \frac{1}{x^2} \left[ 4 \pi \rho \left(\frac{1}{2}(ct + x)\right) + ct\dot{\rho}\left(\frac{1}{2}(ct + x)\right)\right]$$

where $c$ is a positive constant.

Ostensibly one would proceed by finding autocovariance of the random field $g$ given by:
$$K_g(t_1, x_1; t_2, x_2)=\mathbb{E}[g(t_1, x_1)g(t_2, x_2)]$$

I understand that the one can do so after some tedious algebra/differentiation but the problem is that autocovariance function does not turn out to be stationary (or weakly stationary). This renders the usual parametric formulas (e.g., given in Tobby Berger's book Rate Distortion Theory) for the RD function inapplicable. What is a way around this? Any approximate, numerical methods?